# Material Design Not working in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I have added the following dependency
    `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`
in Build.gradle

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        app:iconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
         />
```

regular button is formed but there should be an Outline Button because i have used this style:
`style=@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`

Is there any issue with the minimum Api selected or any other issue please help me with this thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify a background for a material button, remove this line and see what happens: `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"`

Comment: Thanks @DanielNugent But the problem is Material Design elements are not rendering. is there any specific Api level for which it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990021/androidtheme-material-light-requires-api-level-21-current-min-is-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Material component theme as parent in your base application theme. Like below

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="**Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar**">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```